# How to log SQL statements and rows returned in sqlalchemy to aid in debugging?

Tags: debugging, logging, sqlalchemy

How do I configure `sqlalchemy` to log the SQL statements that it's making to the database server, and also log the rows returned from those statements?  This would be useful for debugging.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Option 1: set the `sqlalchemy.engine` logger log level to either `logging.INFO` or `logging.DEBUG`:**
e.g.,

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.basicConfig()
>>> logger = logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine')
>>> logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
>>> session.query(User).all()
2015-01-02 11:54:25,854 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2015-01-02 11:54:25,856 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT users.id AS users_id, users.name AS users_name
FROM users
2015-01-02 11:54:25,857 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2015-01-02 11:54:25,858 DEBUG sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine Col ('users_id', 'users_name')
2015-01-02 11:54:25,860 DEBUG sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine Row (1, u'Alice')
2015-01-02 11:54:25,860 DEBUG sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine Row (2, u'Bob')
```

Reference: [Configuring Logging](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#configuring-logging)

**Option 2: use the `echo` arg when calling `sqlalchemy.create_engine()`:**

e.g.,

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import create_engine
>>> from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
>>> engine = create_engine('postgres://postgres_user:my_password@localhost/my_db',
...                        echo="debug")
>>> Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
>>> session = Session()
>>> users = session.query(User).all()
2015-01-02 11:54:25,854 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2015-01-02 11:54:25,856 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT users.id AS users_id, users.name AS users_name
FROM users
2015-01-02 11:54:25,857 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2015-01-02 11:54:25,858 DEBUG sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine Col ('users_id', 'users_name')
2015-01-02 11:54:25,860 DEBUG sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine Row (1, u'Alice')
2015-01-02 11:54:25,860 DEBUG sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine Row (2, u'Bob')
```

[Per the sqlalchemy documentation:](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/engines.html#engine-creation-api)

> *sqlalchemy.**create_engine** *(*args, **kwargs)*
>   ...
>   **echo=False** – if True, the Engine will log all statements as well as a repr() of their parameter lists to the engines logger, which defaults to sys.stdout. The echo attribute of Engine can be modified at any time to turn logging on and off. If set to the string "debug", result rows will be printed to the standard output as well.

Comment: seems like people have trouble finding this in the docs but you can also [use the Python logging API directly](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/engines.html#configuring-logging) to fully customize how logging runs.

Comment: Thanks @zzzeek!  I have now added that to the answer.