# How can I log sql queries in the SqlModel?

Tags: python, debugging, logging, sqlalchemy, sqlmodel

How could I see/log queries sent by [sqlmodel](https://github.com/tiangolo/sqlmodel) to database.

Comment: You should specify how you create your DB session and which driver you use for more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since sqlmodel uses [Sqlalchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) as backend ORM engine, we can use Sqlalchemy logging answer like [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27748053/how-to-log-sql-statements-and-rows-returned-in-sqlalchemy-to-aid-in-debugging):

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# run sqlmodel code after this
```

You should be able to see sql queries in the console.